# Test in Michael Hartl's Tutorial Chapter 8 Fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I am working on Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial and I am stuck at Chapter 8.4.6 with the Remember Test failing.
I am confused on what to do next.

Here is the test result

```
 FAIL["test_login_with_remembering", UsersLoginTest, 2015-08-25 15:26:59 +0100]
 test_login_with_remembering#UsersLoginTest (1440512819.22s)
    Expected nil to not be nil.
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:52:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
```

Here is my user_login_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

    class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

      def setup
        @user = users(:microte)
      end

      test "login with invalid information" do
        get login_path
        assert_template "sessions/new"
        post login_path, session: { email: "", password: "" }
        assert_template "sessions/new"
        assert_not flash.empty?
        get root_path
        assert flash.empty?
      end

      test "login with valid information" do
        get login_path
        post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'microte' }
        assert_redirected_to @user
        follow_redirect!
        assert_template "users/show"
        assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
        assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
        assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
      end

      test "login with valid information followed by logout" do
        get login_path
        post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'microte' }
        assert_redirected_to @user
        follow_redirect!
        assert_template "users/show"
        assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
        assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
        assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
        delete logout_path
        assert_not is_logged_in?
        assert_redirected_to root_url
        # simulate a user clicking logout in a second window.
        delete logout_path
        follow_redirect!
        assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
        assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path, count: 0
        assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
      end

        test "login with remembering" do
        log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '1')
        assert_not_nil cookies['remember_token'] #line 52
      end

      test "login without remembering" do
        log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '0')
        assert_nil cookies['remember_token']
      end
    end
```

My session_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
      def new
      end

      def create
        user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
        if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
          log_in user
          params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)

          redirect_to user
        else
          flash.now[:danger] = "Invalid e-mail/password combination"
          render "new"
        end
      end

      def destroy
        log_out if logged_in?
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end
```

My test_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
    require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
    require 'rails/test_help'
    require "minitest/reporters"
    Minitest::Reporters.use!

    class ActiveSupport::TestCase
      # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
      fixtures :all

      # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...

      # Returns true if a test user is logged in.
      def is_logged_in?
        !session[:user_id].nil?
      end

      # Log in a test user.
      def log_in_as(user, options = {})
        password = options[:password]     || 'password'
        remember_me = options[:remember_me]  || '1'
        if integration_test?
          post login_path, session: { email:        user.email, 
                                      password:     password,
                                      remember_me:  remember_me }
        else
          session[:user_id] = user.id
        end
      end

        private

        # Returns true inside an integration test.
        def integration_test?
          defined?(post_via_redirect)
        end
    end
```

Users.yml

```
microte:
      name: Lord Microte
      email: lord@microte.com
      password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

I really would appreciate if someone could help out.

Comment: One thing you might do next is highlight for us which line is line 52 of `users_login_test.rb` ... I can't count that high, so your help in identifying the actual line that is causing the error is appreciated.

Comment: I just added a comment to identify it.

Comment: Ok, now it looks like it would be helpful to see what the `log_in_as` method does in your test.

Comment: @SunilD. I have inserted the `test_helper.rb` to show what the `log_in_as` method does

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it was because of password_digest in yml file 
you need to choose one and commit to it.

ex: 
in yml file:

```
password_digest: <%= User.digest('example') %>
```

then

in test_helper.rb

```
def log_in_as(user, options = {})
    password = options[:password]     || 'example'
```

and in user_login_test.rb

```
post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'example' }
```

Comment: Had the same problem as this question and this solved it.

Answer (score 0):

i'm at the same chapter with the same problem. I've tried a lot of way to pass the test, and the strange thing is that the cookies['remember_token'] is nil only in test environment, while all works fine in development environment (i can see the remember_token cookie by inspecting it on the browser).
Anyway, i finished the chapter and start the exercises (the 2nd one), and guess?
Defining user as a instance variable (`@user`) in the `current_user` method in `session_helper.rb` and using `assert_equal cookies['remember_token'], assigns(:user).remember_digest` do the test pass.

I don't know why in the tutorial in 8.15 listing the test is GREEN, because everwhere i looked i found people with the same problem.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks. I was on this for weeks. I felt the issue was from my end to started chapter 8 afresh. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Was experiencing the same issue and went through the chapter again - and found in my app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb

```
def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

instead of:

```
def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    **cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token**
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The 2 snippets look the same.